# How to printf a vector in C

Tags: c

I have three diferent vectors with the name of diferents towns inside:

```
V_NombrePueblos listTown1={"Abrera","Granollers","Cardedeu","Manresa","Martorell"};
V_NombrePueblos listTown2={"Astorga","Benavente","Bembibre","Camarzana","Ferrol"};
V_NombrePueblos listTown3={"Arteijo","Betanzos","Cariño","Cedeira","Cerdido"};
```

The user tell me the number of vector and the position for print the town. I think in use a function with a switch inside for do this:

```
typedef char nameList[8];

void returnTown(int listTown, int position){

  nameList numList;

  if (listTown==0){
     strcpy(numList, "listTown1");
  }

  if (listTown==1){
strcpy(numList, "listTown2");
 }

  if (listTown==2){
    strcpy(numList, "listTown3");
  }

  switch (position){

         case 1:
         printf("%s", numList[0]);
         break;

         case 2:
         printf("%s", numList[1]);
         break;

         case 3:
         printf("%s", numList[2]);
         break;

         case 4:
         printf("%s", numList[3]);
         break;

         case 5:
         printf("%s", numList[4]);
         break;
```

But when I try to print example:
`returnTown(0,1)`

The console doesn't show nothing, with the previus code the console should show "**Abrera**"

The problem is in the printf insede the switch,

If I put:

`printf("%s",listTown1[0] )`
The code show "Abrera" fine, but I need pass the name of the vector like a varName, because sometimes will be listTown1, other times listTown2 or listTown3...

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Before thinking about your question, `strcpy(numList, "listTown1");` is dangerous because `numList` has only 8 elements while 10 elements (9 characters + 1 terminating null-character) are required.

Comment: Ok I can put `typedef char nameList[10];` no problem, but I need use the strcpy, don't have more ways with this custom C language of the university :(

Comment: use a pointer that you assign to listTown1, or listTown2 or ...

Comment: Your switch statement has no case for 0, so it seems to be working properly. Perhaps you could expand your code to a [mcve] so we can see the full picture.

Comment: sorry, there is not a case 0, I edit the post with `returnTown(0,1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying names of variables doesn't mean refering variables.

To refer variables, you should use pointers.

You will want something like this:

```
void returnTown(int listTown, int position){

  V_NombrePueblos* numList;

  switch (listTown){
    case 0: numList = &listTown1; break;
    case 1: numList = &listTown2; break;
    case 2: numList = &listTown3; break;
    default: return;
  }

  if (1 <= position && position <= 5){
    printf("%s", (*numList)[position - 1]);
```

(rest part of this function isn't shown because I respect the original code snippet)

Comment: shouldn't it be be numList = listTownX without & ?

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt No, it shouldn't because I use `V_NombrePueblos* numList;` and therefore *pointers to* `V_NombrePueblos` should be assigned to `numList`.

Comment: You really want to have an array or indexable container of listTown[n].

Comment: maybe this is the solutions, use  a pointer... I need the library stdlib.h and read about this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do won't work in C - you can't build variable names dynamically like that.

Any time you find yourself defining a bunch of variables with the same type and with ordinal names (`var1`, `var2`, etc.), that's a real strong hint you want to use an *array*.  In this case, you could do something like

```
/**
 * I am *assuming* that vNombrePueblos is a typedef name for char *[5],
 * based on the declarations in your code.
 * 
 * The size of the listTowns array is taken from the number of initializers;
 * in this case, 3.  
 */
vNombrePueblos listTowns[] = { 
  {"Abrera","Granollers","Cardedeu","Manresa","Martorell"},
  {"Astorga","Benavente","Bembibre","Camarzana","Ferrol"},
  {"Arteijo","Betanzos","Cariño","Cedeira","Cerdido"}
};
```

This way instead of trying to figure out which `listTownN` variable you want, you just index into this array.  To print out the correct town, all you need is the two indices:

```
/**
 * You need to pass the list of towns as an argument to your function;
 * since arrays lose their "array-ness" under most circumstances, you also
 * have to pass the array size to make sure you don't try to access something
 * past the end of it.  
 */
void returnTown( vNombrePueblos listTowns[], int numTowns, int town, int position )
{
  if ( town < numTowns )
    printf( "%s\n", listTowns[town][position] );
  else
    fprintf( stderr, "No such entry\n" );
}
```

You'll need to keep track of the number of entries in `listTowns` yourself - arrays in C don't carry any metadata about their size, and under most circumstances (such as when you pass it as an argument to a function) an expression of type "array of `T`" will "decay" into an expression of type "pointer to `T`", so the `sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]` trick won't work to get the number of elements.

Comment: thanks for your reply but I can't use this:```vNombrePueblos listTowns[] = { 
  {"Abrera","Granollers","Cardedeu","Manresa","Martorell"},
  {"Astorga","Benavente","Bembibre","Camarzana","Ferrol"},
  {"Arteijo","Betanzos","Cariño","Cedeira","Cerdido"}
};``` I need use 3 diferent arrays, not inside the same, specs of the exercise :(

Comment: Adding check for `0 <= town` and the range of `position` will make your code safer.

Comment: @Torkemada: Then MikeCAT's solution is the one you need to use.

Comment: @JohnBode yes, i'm seeying the mater of the pointers. Thanks both